# How to speed up multiple audio-books files?

Tags: audio, mp3, audiobook

I like listening audiobooks 3x the speed. Audible is great for that.

I also have some books in mp3. 
Is there a way to convert them to 3x speed so that the voice is the same and it sounds like audible?

I would prefer to have a way to convert a number of files. A linux script would be probably the best. A windows program that can work with larger number of files should work too.

**Update**
there is a similar question but i'm looking for a linux script. preferably something that i can easily install with a package manager (apt-get, yum, pacman)

Comment: Do you want to modify the file and write a new copy of the MP3, or do you just want a player that allows for 3X playing?

Comment: modify the file and write a new copy

Answer (score 2):

SoX's `tempo` predicate will modify the speed of the audiobook but not the pitch of the sound.